# Resetting forgotten phpmyadmin password

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin, password-recovery

I recently installed LAMP on Ubuntu 13.04(32-bit) but **forgot my phpMyAdmin password**. How can I reset its password without re-installing it?

Comment: For people having issues with the current accepted answer. I suggest checking out the DigitalOcean article [How To Reset Your MySQL or MariaDB Root Password](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply change or reset your MySQL root password by doing the following:

1. Stop the MySQL server

   ```
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
2. Start mysqld

   ```
   sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. Login to MySQL as root

   ```
   mysql -u root mysql
   ```
4. Change MYSECRET with your new root password

   ```
   UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('MYSECRET') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
   ```
5. Kill mysqld

   ```
   sudo pkill mysqld
   ```
6. Start mysql

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```
7. Login to phpmyadmin as root with your new password

Comment: Can you please explain the use of #2 Start mysqld? Also, how will I be able to execute #3 since I don't remember my MySQL password anymore?

Comment: The idea for #2 is that you are spawning a version of the MySQL daemon *without* a password. This allows you to reset it on step 4.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16 I was not able to run mysqld manually - trying to create socket and socket lock file in a dir that didn't even exist!  But if you look at the very NEXT answer (which is not the accepted answer) that is what I needed - I stupidly forgot the password for the phpmyadmin user, and there it is, in plain text, in the phpmyadmin.conf folder!

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'

Comment: I get `2020-09-22 10:40:17 140163612645568 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.2.14-MariaDB) starting as process 23841 ...
mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2020-09-22 10:40:17 140163612645568 [ERROR] Aborting
` at step **2**

Comment: You might want to use the command `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=root &` for the second step, as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559556/4215651).

Comment: Also, for newer versions of MySQL, or if you're encountering errors relating to the password field (i.e. syntax errors), you should try `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILAGES; exit;` for the third step. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716361/4215651).

Answer (score 38):

You don't actually need to reset your username and password, if you can see them.

In your terminal window, type:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
```

This will open your phpmyadmin configurations.

There, you will see your username under `dbc_dbuser='your_username'` and password under `dbc_dbpass='your_password'`.

Comment: I could not able to find **/etc/dbconfig-common/ ** path. Both "MySQL Database" & "Apache Web Server" running successfully. Any suggestion !! This I'm trying to work on Wordpress.

Comment: Don't forget to restart mysql  " sudo service mysql restart "

Comment: I found a user called `phpmyadmin`, but not my main `root` user. That user also did not have permissions to add new users or databases!

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: I get `Directory '/etc/dbconfig-common' does not exist`

Answer (score 9):

There is a workaround on Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) where there is a second admin account automatically generated by the system called

```
debian-sys-maint
```

You can see (and should not change) its password via

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

It is possible (sure on Ubuntu 16.04) to use that account both in phpMyAdmin as well as in the command line

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
```

The account has exactly the same privileges as phpMyAdmin's / MySQL's root.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why my login was failing even though I never changed the password.

It was failing because I rebootet the server and the mysql server was not startet automatically. So I startet the server and it worked again.