# Reset password for mysql in ubuntu:

Tags: server, password, mysql

Refer from this question ([Resetting forgotten phpmyadmin password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password)) I am trying to reset the password of mysql installed.But run the third command `mysql -u root mysql` i will get the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: N
O).
```

I have searched a lot but cant find  a solution.Currently the virtual machine is running in azure cloud service

Answer (score 1):

To reset your mysqld password just follow these instructions :

Stop the mysql demon process using this command :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Because you are not checking user privs at this point, it's safest to disable networking. In Dapper, `/usr/bin/mysqld...` did not work. However, `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` did.

start the mysql client process using this command

```
mysql -u root
```

from the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then reset/update your password

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

If you have a mysql root account that can connect from everywhere, you should also do:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

[Check this official help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset)

---

If the above method didn't work check this.

Check the version of your `mysql-server`;

```
apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

Now you can know  `mysql-server-X.X` installed in your system.

2. Start the reconfiguration with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-X.X
   ```

This will  prompt  you  to enter your new password and confirm the reconfiguration.

[image: snap1]

3. Now you can log in :

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

Comment: I tried the second method and reset the password.but it again get the same error

Comment: Then purge the server and install again as stated in offcial link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset  But you 'll loose all your mysql data