# Where do I find the random generated password after the phpmyadmin installation?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin in my Ubuntu 12 server, during the installation process with dbconfig-common I left the phpmyadmin password blank. The system said a random password will be generated. That's fantastic but.. where the hell do I find this password???

I searched the web high and low it seems I am the only one with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset the root password of your phpmyadmin by following theses steps:
[Resetting forgotten phpmyadmin password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password)
(sorry for bad english! :-D)

Comment: Your english is more than acceptable :)
Thanks a lot!