# Change of Root Password for PHPMyAdmin Renders Unexpected Output on CLI

Tags: 14.04, command-line, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am unable to login to my root account on phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14.04.4.

I have perused the following and followed the instructions there:

- [Resetting forgotten phpmyadmin password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password)
- [How to change root password for mysql and phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin)

I am getting the following error (`Access denied`):

```
root@phpmyadmin-8gb-sgp1-01-13feb17-2327hrs-8gb-sgp1-01:~# sudo service mysql stop
stop: Unknown instance: 
root@phpmyadmin-8gb-sgp1-01-13feb17-2327hrs-8gb-sgp1-01:~# sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 12052
root@phpmyadmin-8gb-sgp1-01-13feb17-2327hrs-8gb-sgp1-01:~# 170226  1:11:55 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170226  1:11:55 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 12053 ...
mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How do I solve this?

NOTE: even with "sudo mysql -u root mysql" I have the same error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `-p` flag for in order to perform login based on password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

More info [MySql password reset](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset):

Comment: I still hav the same result after using "sudo"